# HTACCESS: URI rewrite everything to index.php (Within the same directory)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a uri: `www.domain.com/leasing/properties/`

Within that directory, I created a file `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I want, is that regardless of that users type after `properties/` (Ej. `www.domain.com/leasing/properties/somethigelse/I-do-not.care/what@#$%they\type`) to be handled by `www.domain.com/leasing/properties/index.php`

I do not need structure or anything else. `index.php` will grab `$_REQUEST['uri']` and check against a database. So, again, I do not care what's typed after `www.domain.com/leasing/properties/` so long `index.php` can get the URI and handle an action according to `$_REQUEST['uri']`

I want the address bar to not not change. Whatever a user types, to remain the same.

The current file is giving me a 404 error.

PS. I know close to nothing about Apache .htaccess

Comment: I would expect what you have to work, except that it might go into a redirect loop, avoidable with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: ...as long as the VirtualHost or Server config has `AllowOverride` configured, needed for any .htaccess to be parsed.

Comment: @michael-berkowski I am not sure what I am doing and do not have Apache training... So, do I add AllowOverride to the root .htaccess file?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride `AllowOverride All` (or more restrictive) has to go in the server httpd.conf or `<VirtualHost>` config to enable directory .htaccess files. You cannot put it in .htaccess. If you're on shared hosting it should be enabled for you already. If it is your own server, you may need to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$     /leasing/properties/ [R]
```

And place it within `/leasing/properties/` folder.

Comment: I noticed I made a mistake. Rather than redirecting (Like in PHP: `header('location: ...');`), I want a rewrite. Any URI entry (On or after `leasing/properties/`) to be handled by `leasing/properties/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/leasing/properties/(.*)$ /leasing/properties/index.php [L,QSA]
```

If that does not work, your Apache server may not be configured to allow `.htaccess` files.

Comment: The website also has another .htaccess file on the root directory. Could it be that it's overriding the one in `leasing/properties/`?

Comment: Yes, if it has rewrite rules. You also need mod_rewrite on the server. Time to read the manual, I think.